# Can you get fully drunk when Stray Sheep is about to close?

Tags: catherine

As with drinking, the time advances when speaking to the other customers: while trying to catch all unique dialogue each night I don't have that much opportunities for alcohol intake  which increases Vincent's movement speed during the puzzle stages (yes, beneficial). I don't know if and when the bar exactly closes, but eventually all but the staff has left. It appears that at this point the glass never gets empty, Vincent can sip from it seemingly endlessly (the internal dialogue lines loop) and the waitress never returns for your orders, giving you only 1/3 of the total "intoxication level" (the character is visibly drunk nonetheless).